# rotation angle between -90 and 90

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, math, scipy

I have two 1d arrays. They are plotted together. They are constructed such that they make angle to one another. the red line is the reference line or you can say axis. In picture 1 this makes theoretically an angle of  positive 36 degrees from the red line. I know this based on my data.

Picture two  has the same referenced line(red) but now the blue line is above it. This is an angle of -36 degrees. So based on my calculation the two arrays are plotting the way it should be.

But now I like to estimate an angle based on how they are plotted. These plots are based on data, which I already know. I now need to make a logic to estimate angles. I was reading that arctan2 would help. But I am not sure why?

Please note that the maximum angle of rotation should not exceed beyong-90 to 90 degrees. So -90 above the red line and 90 bel0w the red line, in my case.

Thanks
sal

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is basic trigonometry.  The angle of a line from the x axis is `arctan(dy/dx)`.  So, ypu need two points on each line.  We can use `(0,Y0)`, where Y0 is the Y coordinate of both lines when X=0.  Then, say we have `(xb1,yb1)` as some point on the blue line, and `(xr1,yr1)` as some point on the red line.  Then we have:

```
import math
# Angle of red line from horizontal
theta_r = math.atan( (yr1-y0) / xr1 )
# Angle of blue line from horizontal
theta_b = math.atan( (yb1-y0) / xb1 )
# Difference
delta = theta_r - theta_b
```

If both lines are in the first quadrant, there's no need for `atan2`.  The simpler `atan` will do.

The result here will be in radians.  If you want degrees, you can do

```
degrees = delta * 180 / math.pi
```

Comment: thanks. But in my work, the angles above red line are in negative and below should be positive. I think your solution reference from x axis.,, considering one quadrant. I learned form your response, that my solution requires two quadrants. If I implement atan2, wil the red line be reference as 0 degrees?

Comment: I did exactly what you said.  My `theta` values are referenced from the X axis, but when I subtract them, the result is relative to the red line.  If blue is above, then `theta_b` is larger and the value is negative.  Did you even try it?

Comment: The only difference between `atan` and `atan2` in that sample is that the `atan2` would have a comma where I have a divide (`/`).

Comment: Thanks Tim. I applied it. i plug in the following values, GG=redline, rcc3bulk=blue line. I do not have x axis saved. so i just give them index value. y0=GG[0]
    yr1=GG[5]
    xr1=5
    yb1=rcc3Bulk[5]
    xb1=5   i got degrees =018, i am expecting 36

Comment: I tried your implementation. I would have given  it a right answer if you had address the part, where the part of the problem is that area above red line is from 0 to -90. below is 0 to 90. this red line actually is 90 division, which is shown as 45. I guess i need to ask a new question. any comments are welcome. Your answer is right theoretically, but did not specifically respond to my question.